# Is there any SEO benefit in having a site archived by archive.org's "Wayback Machine"?

Tags: seo, internet-archive

Is there any SEO benefit of having a site frequently archived by the Wayback Machine vs. being completely excluded?

Comment: Interesting question, I don't have a complete answer sadly. One reason I can think of however, is if a page on your live site goes 404, someone can link to a web archive copy, and whoever visits that copy later can continue to the rest of your website. I've been replacing dead URLs with archive copies in my Stackexchange answers which linked or referred to some tutorials from years ago that are no longer online.

Comment: I've removed my website from archive.org, and haven't seen a drop in traffic. To go on a short rant, I dislike the attitude of privilege some archival sites have. Some sites hotlinked images on my website, so the library of congress thinks it is their responsibility to crawl those images every so often to get a complete and current copy of those images, regardless of my site being foreign and friendly signals to keep out, like robots.txt

Comment: archive.org is a piracy site. They have tons of video games (complete library, NES, SNES, N64, WII, Gamecube, PS1, PS2, PS3) Movies, TV shows, Music, EVERYTHING.
Pay no taxes and take millions in donations.
A WIN-WIN-WIN situation. The scam of the century. Then you will see folks defending it, ofc, cos they pirate from it too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found zero SEO benefit to Wayback Machine. WM is a very cool tool, and can work as a great reference and research app, but the benefit for SEO would be practically nonexistent.

For one thing, Wayback Machine pages are not something that would normally appear very high in SERPs. Oh sure, a search for `site:web.archive.org` will give you some 56K results in the SERPs. But you'll rarely find them ranking highly for any but the most obscure search query. And if they were, the rank would be for WM, not your site.

Here's how a sample WM Macy's URL will appear in SERPs, if it even gets indexed:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100226024516/http://macys.com/

Now let's say someone does research on your site, and finds some page, and starts to click around on there. They won't be taken to your current site; they'll be clicking within the WM iframe of your old site. So let's say we hit the above Macy's page and click on a top nav menu link. We get to:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100323171904/http://www1.macys.com/catalog/index.ognc?CategoryID=1405&PageID=6036169698215&cm_sp=global_nav_reg-_-gifts_&_gift_cards-_-n

Again, it's essentially their URL.

Even if you could click through to the current site, or if someone got inspired and went to it directly, that's just web traffic. Number of clicks is not a ranking metric for SEO.

So this is more for the user, not the search engine.

Comment: I agree with you from technical standpoint. Do you think it's possible Google takes it as a metric? I mean giving archived sites more value? I hope it doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelRogers There are definitely some archives that can send signals to search engines that there is a lot of useful content on the internet about a certain entity. There are also tools like WikiData that contribute to search engines' understanding of an entity. WM is more a fun snapshot tool, and as such, doesn't quite send signals; good thing too, because some of those archived snapshots don't work properly, or provide a view that you would rather forget.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen sites with millions of views a month have HUGE amount of pages indexed in Archive.org. There has to be some correaltion here. I would like to do a joint test with another SEO if you are up to it. Lets test out some ideas and report back. I remember when Alexa used to be a "ranking" signal back in the day. There could be some benefit. Even being listed on that site must help in some way. With that being said, I have blocked Archive from indexing some of my sites, and had no problems with indexing in the SERPS.